# Integration of exponential trig functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

If $\cos^2x=[1+\cos(2x)]/2=(1/2)[1+\cos(2x)]$

Would I be wrong in assuming that $$\cos^2(3x+1)=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\cos[2(3x+1)]\right]=\frac{1}{2}\cos(6x+2)+\frac{1}{2}?$$

---

I'm trying to take the $\int \cos^2(3x+1)dx$

The solution breaks $\int \cos^2(t)dt$ into $\left[\frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\sin(t)+\frac{1}{2}\int 1 dt\right]$

**Can I do this integral with either substitution, or is the latter the correct process and why?**

Comment: there is some mistake you missed 1

Comment: Either approach will work.  Note that the two anti-derivative expressions will differ by a numerical constant, which is "absorbed" by the arbitrary constant $ \ C \ . $

Answer (score 1):

look please there

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28cos%283*x%2B1%29%29%5E2
```

you missed $1$ somewhere

namely in your answer it should be

$cos^{2}(3*x+1)=1/2(1+cos(2*(3*x+1))$,

from where after simply calculation we get

$(1+cos(6*x+2))/2$

or

$1/2 +cos(6*x+2)/2$

now if we integrate we get

$x/2+ sin(6*x+2)/12$

Comment: That was my mistake. I meant to add the 1 in. BUT is $x/2+sin(6∗x+2)/12+C$ the same as $\left[12cos(t)sin(t)+12\int 1dt\right]+C$

Comment: it should be yes,you can try  wolfram integrator like http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: In the substitution approach, remember that $ \ t = 3x + 1 \ \Rightarrow \ dx = \frac{1}{3} dt \ . $ Be careful with the constant multipliers.  Both results will agree up to a numerical constant.